# Want button click sound to persist from scene to scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-storage

I created an Audiosource from an audio click on all button hits. However, it gets deleted when clicking a button that loads a new scene. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to fix this, like how to add "Dontdestroyonload()" to the audio source somehow.

Code is below:

```
  private void PlaySound()
    {
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(buttonClick, Camera.main.transform.position);
        
    }

    public void LoadStartMenu()
    {
        PlaySound();
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can try like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class ClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
  private AudioSource _audioSource;
  private void Awake()
  {
     _audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
  }
 
  public void PlaySound()
  {
     if (_audioSource.isPlaying) return;
  _audioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(buttonClick,Camera.main.transform.position);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).